# Sleep(x) causes computer to sleep instead

Tags: c++, windows, sleep

This is probably one of the strangest things I've encountered so far in C++:

```
while(counter != stop_value)
{
    //Part A starting
    ip.ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    ip.ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    //Part A ending

    if (s == 2) counter++;
    else counter--;
    cout << counter; //for debugging
    Sleep(i);
}
```

Whenever I comment the "Part A"-part away, it works properly; the program sleeps for `i` seconds, depending on user input. However, as soon as I add the easy way of triggering the return-key again, it makes my whole computer sleep instead (AKA, the screen goes entirely black for `i` seconds). I've tried googling, but I can't find anything about this.

And, this is only a small part of the code. I have added the INPUT class and everything further up. `s` is also a user-defined variable, that (in this case) can vary between 2 and 3. If equal to two, the counter's value will be set to 0, and it will increase until it has reached its max value (which is user-defined, and set to `stop-value`). While using **this** method, the `sleep` function works properly, and only the program "pauses" for `i` seconds. HOWEVER, as soon as a user set `s` to 3, it will start decreasing from the max value (user-defined) until it has reached its stop-value, which always is equal to zero. When this happens, the screen gets a blackout instead.

I've tried debugging for ages now, and I just can't seem to find the solution... Since the code is way more complex than this, and I'd need to use way more space (which I don't want to), I'll give you some inputs for the variables you can use instead:

- **Working input:** `counter = 0; stop_value = 21; s = 2; i = 1000;`
- **Input leading to screen blackout:** `counter = 20; stop_value = 0; s = 3; i = 1000;`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If (assuming you're using Visual Studio) you highlight `Sleep` and press F12, it should take you to the header where it's defined.  This should be `WinBase.h` from the Windows SDK.  If it's going to a different function, then that is your problem.

Comment: Side note: you'd better setup remote debugging - generally send keyboard events and focus related problems are very hard to debug on the same machine...

Comment: Pretty undiagnosable, what kind of window or widget exactly gets this keystroke?  Keep it away from the "Format drive" menu item.

Comment: @benjymous I always get to synchapi.h using `sleep`. However, it still doesn't make sense to me why it works sometimes, and sometimes not...

Comment: @Hans Passant Not quite sure of what you mean. Whatever that's highlighted gets the keystroke, and it's nothing that I've been thinking of that much (I might have misunderstood you though. What do you mean with "gets this keystroke"?). And, I'm not certain of what you mean with "keeping it away from "format drive" menu item" either.

Comment: @Max, Hans wants to know where that "Enter" key ends up.  Precisely.  What is it?  And he is a bit tongue in cheek, but there was a Format Drive menu item that was receiving the keystroke, well.. yes...

Comment: Are you setting the `type` of `ip` to `INPUT_KEYBOARD`?  and are you using `ZeroMemory` on the structure prior to use?

Comment: @Moo-Juice Wow, I just found this piece of code a bit further up: `if (s != 3) ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;`... Some major things have changed today, and as it seems, some minor things like that have just slipped right past my eyes. I'll try it, and I'll see if it makes any difference. Thanks! **EDIT:** Amazing! It works just fine. Thanks a lot, really. Was kind of stupid of me to miss such an obvious thing, so sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May as well stick it as an answer :)

Are you setting the type of `ip` to `INPUT_KEYBOARD`? and are you using `ZeroMemory` on the structure prior to use?

Comment: As said deep down in the comments above, I had accidently forgotten to make sure of that the type is set to `INPUT_KEYBOARD` while `s = 3`. Thanks again!